# haproxy vs squid ssl bump and dynamic generation

Tags: squid, haproxy

I would like to know if following 2 features of squid are available in haproxy?

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/DynamicSslCert
http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump

any help would be really appreciated.

Cheerz

Answer (score 1):

Squid and haproxy are two very different products. Those features make no sense to be a part of haproxy.

Answer (score 1):

Longneck is right, but to fully answer your question: No.

HAproxy doesn't support that feature and almost certainly never will.